# iMacros: Wait until a page loads for javascript post links

Tags: post, imacros

On some pages, there are some links that would call a javascript to send a post request and load another page. The only way I know to load those pages is a TAG command, however when I use TAG, apparently iMacros does not understand that a page is being loaded and it will continue the rest of the code immediately. Is there any way to make iMacros expect a loading page?

And yes I have tried !WAITPAGECOMPLETE and !TIMEOUT_PAGE already! The execution jumps over them like it does not expect a page being loaded at all.

As an example you can try the "next" link bellow the table at http://update.dotic.ir/eBookLibrary/frmDictionary.aspx

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to play around with images if the `TAG` command should work perfectly:

```
URL GOTO=http://update.dotic.ir/eBookLibrary/frmDictionary.aspx
SET !EXTRACT_TEST_POPUP NO

TAG XPATH="//b[@class='dxp-num dxp-current']" EXTRACT=TXT
TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:2
' time limit for the table to change
SET !TIMEOUT_STEP 100
TAG XPATH="//b[@class='dxp-num dxp-current'][not(text()='{{!EXTRACT}}')]"
SET !EXTRACT NULL

TAG XPATH="//b[@class='dxp-num dxp-current']" EXTRACT=TXT
TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:3
TAG XPATH="//b[@class='dxp-num dxp-current'][not(text()='{{!EXTRACT}}')]"
SET !EXTRACT NULL

' and so on

SET !TIMEOUT_STEP 6
```